# LSTM - Imbalance dataset - Low recall

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I am having trouble with LSTM and kind a stuck. The problem is my precision is coming out to be **.60-0.80** but **recall is really low** **0.002-0.20**

I have an imabalance dataset problem to sort that out i am using **tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits** but it seems its still not working

where self.pos_class_weight is

```
class1weight = max(0.00001, (np.size(y)) / (float(np.sum(y)) + 0.0001))
```

which is ok, i validated it.

```
losses = tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, targets=y, pos_weight=self.pos_class_weight)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(losses)
self.train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.005).minimize(loss)
```

Somehow my intuition is that the above way of handiling imabalnce dataset problem is not correct.

The problem is even i am trying to intentionally over-fit (it is not doing that).
I just want to increase the recall, let the precision get low, but its not happening now, even after increasing hidden layer size and using stacked LSTM layers.

I am missing something very basic but dont know what it is, can anyone help, or point me to a resource which is dealing with imbalance dataset problem with LSTM preferably.

Comment: Have you considered stratified sampling to address the imbalanced dataset?

Comment: cant, its a sequence labeling problem, think like in an unstructured text i am labeling some entities. So i cant play with class sizes or the order in which they are given as input